# dashboard python API

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard

I have 6 charts that I wish to embed in a Plotly dashboard using the Python API in a 3 rows x 2 column configuration.

I am expecting the following:
[layout of boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtcFH.png)

```
    dashboard.insert(box_1)
    dashboard.insert(box_2,'below',1)
    dashboard.insert(box_3, 'below', 2)
    dashboard.insert(box_4,'right',1)
    dashboard.insert(box_5,'right',2)
    dashboard.insert(box_6,'right',3)

    dash_url = py.dashboard_ops.upload(dashboard, dashboard_name, auto_open=True)
```

The above code is not rendering them in the order I am after and I want to understand why and what the correct approach is.